# My tuple is getting a Product with java.io.Serializable type error, my types seem to match correctly

Tags: scala

I have a function that looks like:

```
case class User(name: String)
val users = List(User("a"), User("b"), User("c"))
val bannedUsers = List(User("b"))

def processUsers(
    users: Set[User],
    bannedUsers: Set[User]
): Set[Either[(String, Int), Boolean]] = {
  users.map { u =>
    verifyUsers(users, bannedUsers).flatMap { verifiedUsers =>
      verifiedUsers.name match {
        case "a" => Right(true)
        case "b" => Right(true)
        case "c" =>
          Left(("hello", 3))
      }
    }

  }
}

def verifyUsers(
    users: Set[User],
    bannedUsers: Set[User]
): Either[String, User] = {
  val n = util.Random.nextInt(users.size)
  Right(users.iterator.drop(n).next)
}
```

println(processUsers(users.toSet, bannedUsers.toSet))

I am getting a compile time error saying:

> type mismatch; [error]  found   : scala.util.Either[Product with
> java.io.Serializable,Boolean]

The types seem to match in my view, what is wrong?

castie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/z1bBfOMpRPyV88VekNdz6w

Comment: which line are you getting that error on? And what does the complete error message look like?

Comment: Can you create an **Scastie** that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What are the types of `method1` and `method2`?

Comment: It looks like the problem is most likely in either `method1` or `method2`. Can you at least provide their type signatures?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez here is a castie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/z1bBfOMpRPyV88VekNdz6w

Comment: Your types do NOT match. `Either[String, X]` vs `Either[(String, Int), X]`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should do `Left(str -> user)` or `Left((str, user))`, Scala deprecated auto-tupling arguments since it caused too many errors in practice so it might cause errors.
2. You probably messed up the return type of a previous pat of code e.g. have some `Right(User(1))` earlier in `flatMap` before doing `Left(...)` in else. `Case class`es (and tuples) implement `scala.Product` and `java.io.Serializable`, so inferring this is a sign of using bad values.
3. `flatMap` in `Either` changes the type of `Right` so you most likely did something like `Right(value: User).flatMap(... => Left((str, user)))` forcing compiler to infer common type of e.g. `User` and `(User, String)`.

Long story short adjust the left type of `method2` before `flatMap` or use some `leftmap`.

Comment: That didn't change anything for me, same error with `Left((str, user))`

Comment: updated my quesition with the match expression if that could be related...

Comment: strange b/c I am not using the value from the .flatMap, I am creating a new string and user object...

Comment: I updated with a scastie...

Comment: As I said, you had misaligned left type - see https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Qo3z6tlgT6CakKOMKOzc9w - see `.left.map`

Comment: yes, but confused as the value (str, 1) is just madeup and meaningless...I can't just make a new value up ...?   thanks for your help..

Comment: Then you have a bad definition of error. If things fails on first function you'll get e.g. `Left("foo")`. If they fail on second you'd get `Left(("foo", 3))`. 2 different types of errors! You cannot magically solve this issue and type system is simply telling you about the problem. You have to solve it youself by coming up with such a type that both of function errors could be converted to without the loss of information.